# Spring-Boot: alternative to Stormpath

Tags: java, spring, rbac

we want to develop an application using Java 8, Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. For user management we would like to implement a normal RBAC. I found "Stormpath" and its exactly what we want. But the biggest headache we have here is that our user data will lie not only on servers outside of our company, but in the US. That's a big nogo for us.

I suppose there is no possibilty to install a copy of stormpath on our Servers. So Do you know any alternatives which provide the same level of functionality and support?

Comment: I don't known why some people downvoted this question, because it's just a good one... So i upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, I've found the [KeyCloack](http://www.keycloak.org/) opensource project. It seems to be a really good self-hosted and free alternative to [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/), [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) or other SaaS user management solution.

As it runs on Java, it's seems it's possible to [embed it in a Spring Boot Application](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-keycloak-server-example).

You can also let the KeyCloack server application run standalone and use OAuth2 features to secure any other application.